# Test strategy/plan creation

Tags: web-application, rest-api, test-planning, test-strategy, desktop-application

I have to create a test plan for my project and present it to the stakeholders. The Test plan should comprise of :

1. Testing types
2. Test Environment
3. Test Data

Project components :

1. Thick client application (.net)
2. APIs being created
3. Data batches are being created
4. Web UI is being created

Currently, there are no environments as well. I need to create a test plan for this project. What should I put in under different areas in test plan like test types, environment, data (if I require managed data),  or any other component in test plan I need?

Comment: What work have you done so far?  We aren’t here to do your work for you.

Comment: I wanted some pointers and not the actual work. If you have some pointers, feel free to pitch otherwise help someone else who needs it :)

Answer (score 1):

James Bach created the [Heuristic Testing Strategy Model](http://www.satisfice.com/tools/htsm.pdf) as a tool to exercises of test plan creation.

It is divided in 5 areas:

- **Project Environment** includes resources, constraints, and other elements in the project that may  enable or hobble our testing. Sometimes a tester must challenge constraints, and sometimes accept them.
- **Product Elements** are things that you intend to test. Software is complex and invisible.Take care to cover all of it that matters, not just the parts that are easy to see.
- **Quality Criteria** are the rules, values, and sources that allow you as a tester to determine if the product has problems. Quality criteria are multidimensional and often hidden or self-contradictory.
- **Test Techniques** are heuristics for creating tests. All techniques involve some sort of analysis of project environment, product elements, and quality criteria.
- **Perceived Quality** is the result of testing. You can never know the “actual” quality of a software product, but through the application of a variety of tests, you can make an informed assessment of it.

I have created a mind-map of this model; you can check it on my blog here: 
[The Heuristic Testing Strategy Model Mindmap](http://thatsabug.com/2018/06/18/the-heuristic_testing_strategy_model_mindmap_.html)